# Scrollbar won't load or resize until the screen is resized

Tags: jquery, css, html, scrollbar

I'm working on a website for a client and need some help. For some reason, the scrollbars on each "page" don't load or change height until the window is resized. I have a jQuery scrollbar replacing the normal scrollbars, but this isn't it, as when I disable those, the normal scrollbar does the same thing. The content is stored inside a child div of the scrolling div, but the content div's height isn't changing when the content changes. Turning the code from the $(window).resize (shown below) into its own function doesn't work either.

http://brianandsacha.tumblr.com/

It's not the worst thing ever, but is VERY annoying.

EDIT: I added the entire JS code, with the edits suggested by Max Dunn. It still does the same thing.

```
        //--details
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#info").show();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#elephant').click(function() {
                if ($('#info').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#info').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //--stay
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#stay").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#gator').click(function() {
                if ($('#stay').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#stay').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();

            });
        });
        //--todo
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#todo").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#man').click(function() {
                if ($('#todo').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#todo').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //--nav
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#nav").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#woman').click(function() {
                if ($('#nav').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#nav').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //--gifts
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#gifts").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#bird').click(function() {
                if ($('#gifts').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#gifts').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //--contact
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#contact").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dog').click(function() {
                if ($('#contact').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#contact').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });

        //--photos
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#photos").hide();
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cat').click(function() {
                if ($('#photos').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#photos').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#info').hide();
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#welcome').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").show();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //welcome
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#welcome").show();
            $("#bubblecontent").hide();
            $('#header').click(function() {
                if ($('#welcome').css('display') == "none")
                    $('#welcome').fadeIn('slow'),
                    $('#stay').hide();
                    $('#todo').hide();
                    $('#nav').hide();
                    $('#gifts').hide();
                    $('#contact').hide();
                    $('#photos').hide();
                    $("#bubblecontent").hide();
                    resizeBubble();
            });
        });
        //bubbleheight
        function resizeBubble() {
            var divHeight = $(document).height() - 300;
            $('#bubble').css({height: divHeight});
        };
        $(window).resize(
        function() {
            resizeBubble();
        });

    body {
        overflow-y: hidden;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        font-family: "museo-slab", georgia, serif;
        font-weight: 100;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    #bubble {
        background-color: #f5fec3;
        height: 100%;
        width: 900px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-radius: 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 15px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
    #bubblecontent {
        width: 860px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

<div id="container">
  <div id="bubble">
    <div id="bubblecontent">
      <div id="contentdiv1">
        blah
      </div>
      <div id="contentdiv2">
        blah
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am leaving my other answer because it might help other people experiencing a similar problem. However after looking at this specific javascript code, there were a lot of areas for improvement so I rewrote the code. The important change was to use the mCustomScrollbar("update") function when the content changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //loading
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
  });

  $(document).ready(function () {
    //elephant
    loadImage1 = new Image();
    loadImage1.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/JN3m8jui6/elephanthover.png";
    staticImage1 = new Image();
    staticImage1.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/j7Fm8jufs/elephant.png";
    //gator
    loadImage2 = new Image();
    loadImage2.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/DoNm8jujc/alligatorhover.png";
    staticImage2 = new Image();
    staticImage2.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/q9Em8jujy/alligator.png";
    //man
    loadImage3 = new Image();
    loadImage3.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/AKZm8jvs5/manhover.png";
    staticImage3 = new Image();
    staticImage3.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/xZam8jvbc/man.png";
    //woman
    loadImage4 = new Image();
    loadImage4.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/AH6m8jvvq/womanhover.png";
    staticImage4 = new Image();
    staticImage4.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/seym8jvup/woman.png";
    //bird
    loadImage5 = new Image();
    loadImage5.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/HY8m8phuj/birdhover.png";
    staticImage5 = new Image();
    staticImage5.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/0jkm8jvz1/bird.png";
    //dog
    loadImage6 = new Image();
    loadImage6.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/sxcm8gfjf/doghover.png";
    staticImage6 = new Image();
    staticImage6.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/2qKm8jw17/dog.png";
    //cat
    loadImage7 = new Image();
    loadImage7.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/ex8mc60c7/cathover.png";
    staticImage7 = new Image();
    staticImage7.src = "http://static.tumblr.com/spps9en/MKomc6065/cat.png";

    function resizeBubble() {
      var divHeight = $(document).height() - 300;
      $('#bubble').css({height: divHeight});
    };

    $(window).resize(function () {
      resizeBubble();
    });

    function updateScroll() {
      $("#bubble").mCustomScrollbar("update");
    }

    function hideAll() {
      $("#welcome").hide();
      $("#info").hide();
      $("#stay").hide();
      $("#todo").hide();
      $("#nav").hide();
      $("#gifts").hide();
      $("#contact").hide();
      $("#photos").hide();
    }

    function switchSection(sectionId) {
      if ($(sectionId).css('display') == "none") {
        hideAll();
        $(sectionId).fadeIn('slow');
        updateScroll();
      }
    }

    $('#elephant').click(function () {
      switchSection('#info')
    });
    $('#gator').click(function () {
      switchSection('#stay')
    });
    $('#man').click(function () {
      switchSection('#todo')
    });
    $('#woman').click(function () {
      switchSection('#nav')
    });
    $('#bird').click(function () {
      switchSection('#gifts')
    });
    $('#dog').click(function () {
      switchSection('#contact')
    });
    $('#cat').click(function () {
      switchSection('#photos')
    });
    $('#header').click(function () {
      switchSection('#welcome')
    });

    // Initial state
    hideAll();
    resizeBubble();
    $("#bubble").mCustomScrollbar({set_width:false});
    switchSection('#welcome');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!

This totally fixed the problem- I didn't realize mCustomScrollbar even did that. I'm kind of new to javascript and jQuery, too, so thanks for reorganizing the code!

Answer (score 0):

First, make the resize code a function:

```
function resizeBubble() {
  var divHeight = $(document).height() - 300;
  $('#bubble').css({height: divHeight});
};
```

Then call this function after you show the first hidden div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#info").show;
  resizeBubble();
};
```

The reason to call it here rather than another $(document).ready is that you don't know what order the $(document).ready will fire in, and it is likely it is firing before you show any divs.

You will also need to add the resizeBubble() call to the end of all of your click() functions as well as $(window).resize.

Comment: That seems like it should've helped, but it in fact did nothing. It just does the same thing as before. Weird, huh? :/

Comment: Can you please add your javascript code to the question. There is probably something subtle in there that I missed.